# Intellij Enum indenting on override methods

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I have enum values which override a method, it formats the braces as such.

[image]

I have to manually correct each one to the following by highlighting the area and pressing shift+tab. Is there any way to set in the style options to not indent in this case? I can't find anything regarding this.

[image]

Comment: Cross post with the forum at JetBrains and already answered there: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000661019-Incorrect-enum-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Answered on JetBrains community forums.

Not yet implemented